# Как использовать функции иных приложений через Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

На моем персональном компьютере установлено приложение "Foxit Reader" для работы с PDF-файлами. У этого приложения есть удобная функция сохранения PDF-файла в виде текстового документа, при этом текст и его расположение сохраняется довольно точно. Можно ли как-то использовать функцию этого приложения в своем коде Python, чтобы в последующем уже проводить работу с создаваемым текстовым файлом???

Comment: используйте [одну из многочисленных опенсорсных библиотек для конвертации pdf в txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767511/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-in-python-3-7), зачем вам посредники? ))

Comment: Посмотрите на готовые библиотеки python это проще всего. Если хотите именно приложение то вариант через командную строку (если такой режим поддерживается в Foxit Reader), если нет то не судьба.

Comment: @Jack_oS готовые библиотеки уже все перепробовал.. PyPDF2 считывает не весь текст, а pdfminer копирует весь текст сплошником без перехода на новую строку, в связи с чем работать с ним практически невозможно(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22898159/14785750 про новую строку в pdfminer

Comment: есть еще такая штука wkhtmltopdf